# TabLayout Icon not showing

Tags: android, icons, imagespan

I'm trying to make tab with tablayout following this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#add-custom-view-to-tablayout

Now I'm trying to show icon instead of text using the imagespan. But without luck, can anyone help point out what is missing from this tutorial?

Here's the code

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

//Fragments List
public ArrayList <Fragment> fragmentList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    setUpFragmentList();

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.home_viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new HomeFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), HomeActivity.this, fragmentList));

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    //start this 2 are to set the tab to fill entire screen
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    //end this 2 are to set the tab to fill entire screen

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_down_activity);

}

private void setUpFragmentList() {
    fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    fragmentList.add(new MyActivitesFragment());
    fragmentList.add(new ChatListFragment());
    fragmentList.add(new QuickMatchFragment());
    fragmentList.add(new FilterMatchFragment());
}
}


public class HomeFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" ,"Tab4"};
private Context context;

private ArrayList <Fragment> fragmentList;

private int[] imageResId = {
        // unclicked
        R.drawable.ic_tab_down_activity,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_down_chat,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_down_find,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_down_filter
};

public HomeFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, ArrayList <Fragment> fragmentList) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return sb;
}
}
```

Comment: That part looks fine, show all of your tabs code.

Answer (score 5):

In your custom tab layout file, just make textAllCaps to false. It will work :)
Reason, the image is being converted to characters, then if it is true, then converting them to capital will not render the image.

```
<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it solved my problem!

Added MyCustomTabTextAppearance in styles.xml and set up app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance" attribute on android.support.design.widget.TabLayout view under activity xml.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently i've found out the solution by using TabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(imageResId[i]);

at first my intention is to be able to set all the icon from viewpager adapter. but since i got no idea nor time to find the solution. i would instead use this other trick i found out.

and also to switch image around i use TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener

hope this helps someone who needed this too. =]

Answer (score 0):

well I guess you are missing the main point in your xml. Set text Appearance style for your tab layout. i.e textAllCaps = false otherwise image span won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't add any tab.

Add a tab like this:
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab One"));.